# Order in executing specflow features

Tags: nunit, bdd, specflow

Can I somehow force execution order in my features and scenarios  or in Nunit tests which are generated from specflow feature file?
It would be nice if I could first test all my data entering features, and than data modifying and than data deleting features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that's more of a question for your test runner of choice.  SpecFlow generates the tests for you from your test file, but it does not run them.  You might be able to direct your test runner to run the scenarios in the order you ask.

However, my advice is that you do not attempt to order your tests.  Each scenario should be be completely independent from others, so that the order the tests are run has no impact on the results.  I guess it depends on what you mean by it being "nice" if they are run in a specific order. :)

Comment: By being nice I mean that if I have tests for adding data to some storage, modifying data form storage and deleting data from storage. It would be nice to order them in that way, because I won't have to add data before deletion tests or modifying tests... Ok, I should listen to your advice and make tests independant

Comment: I'd say to to give independent tests a try, I think you'll find that it makes things much easier to handle when you application grows.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using resharper pluggin to run the tests. So here is what is did to make them in a order ( I know it is not the best idea, but I have a special case. :) )

Resharper orders the tests in the alphabetical order for a given feature file.

So I named  the scenarios with prefixes 1,2,3 and so on based on the order i want them to run.

Dirty, but ok method if you are desperate ;)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that in Nunit too, but it is said that Nunit doesn't guarantee the order of tests. So this may be in alphabetical order for some time, and than they may decide to change implementation. It is not for sure, I cannot rely on that.